IOException while creating a Kubernetes Fabric8 POD from Temporal workflow
We are launching a Temporal Workflow, which is supposed to create a POD and perform some tasks. But while execution, a workflow is created, but getting error while creating the POD.
Here is the error:
{"message":"Failure exceeds size limit.","source":"","stackTrace":"","encodedAttributes":null,"cause":{"message":"An error has occurred.","source":"JavaSDK","stackTrace":"io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:129)\nio.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:122)\nio.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.CreateOnlyResourceOperation.create(CreateOnlyResourceOperation.java:44)\nio.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:1155)\nio.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:98)\nio.floda.platform.workflow.SourceConnectionMetadataActivityImpl.createPod(SourceConnectionMetadataActivityImpl.java:166)\nio.floda.platform.workflow.SourceConnectionMetadataActivityImpl.connectAndDiscover(SourceConnectionMetadataActivityImpl.java:58)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\njava.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\nio.temporal.internal.activity.RootActivityInboundCallsInterceptor$POJOActivityInboundCallsInterceptor.executeActivity(RootActivityInboundCallsInterceptor.java:64)\nio.temporal.internal.activity.RootActivityInboundCallsInterceptor.execute(RootActivityInboundCallsInterceptor.java:43)\nio.temporal.internal.activity.ActivityTaskExecutors$BaseActivityTaskExecutor.execute(ActivityTaskExecutors.java:107)\nio.temporal.internal.activity.ActivityTaskHandlerImpl.handle(ActivityTaskHandlerImpl.java:124)\nio.temporal.internal.worker.ActivityWorker$TaskHandlerImpl.handleActivity(ActivityWorker.java:278)\nio.temporal.internal.worker.ActivityWorker$TaskHandlerImpl.handle(ActivityWorker.java:243)\nio.temporal.internal.worker.ActivityWorker$TaskHandlerImpl.handle(ActivityWorker.java:216)\nio.temporal.internal.worker.PollTaskExecutor.lambda$process$0(PollTaskExecutor.java:105)\njava.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\njava.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\njava.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\n","encodedAttributes":null,"cause":{"message":"kubernetes.default.svc","source":"JavaSDK","stackTrace":"io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.waitForResult(OperationSupport.java:504)\nio.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:524)\nio.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.handleCreate(OperationSupport.java:340)\nio.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:754)\nio.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:98)\nio.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.CreateOnlyResourceOperation.create(CreateOnlyResourceOperation.java:42)\nio.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:1155)\nio.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:98)\nio.floda.platform.workflow.SourceConnectionMetadataActivityImpl.createPod(SourceConnectionMetadataActivityImpl.java:166)\nio.floda.platform.workflow.SourceConnectionMetadataActivityImpl.connectAndDiscover(SourceConnectionMetadataActivityImpl.java:58)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\njava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\njava.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\nio.temporal.internal.activity.RootActivityInboundCallsInterceptor$POJOActivityInboundCallsInterceptor.executeActivity(RootActivityInboundCallsInterceptor.java:64)\nio.temporal.internal.activity.RootActivityInboundCallsInterceptor.execute(RootActivityInboundCallsInterceptor.java:43)\nio.temporal.internal.activity.ActivityTaskExecutors$BaseActivityTaskExecutor.execute(ActivityTaskExecutors.java:107)\nio.temporal.internal.activity.ActivityTaskHandlerImpl.handle(ActivityTaskHandlerImpl.java:124)\nio.temporal.internal.worker.ActivityWorker$TaskHandlerImpl.handleActivity(ActivityWorker.java:278)\nio.temporal.internal","encodedAttributes":null,"cause":null,"applicationFailureInfo":{"type":"java.io.IOException","nonRetryable":false,"details":null}},"applicationFailureInfo":{"type":"io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException","nonRetryable":false,"details":null}},"serverFailureInfo":{"nonRetryable":false}} 
Any leads or help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
I have tried changing some dependencies in pom.xml and some minor configs, but still the POD is not being created.

Update: We are deploying everything on Windows and somehow we missed starting the Minukube locally. Executed minikube start. Now, the POD is being created.
